# What is the OllyDbg SFX Feature equivalent in IDA Pro to find the OEP?

Tags: ida, ollydbg

OllyDbg has this nice feature to find the OEP called SFX:

[image]

IDA has the universal PE Unpacker plugin but it works a little bit different.

**What is the OllyDbg SFX Feature equivalent in IDA Pro to find the OEP?**